# Retrieve ID from entity in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

I am trying to output the results of a query into an HTML table and put a link next to it that deletes the entity.

How do I retrieve the ID of each entity from the datastore so that the delete link knows which entity it needs to delete?. I am using Python/Webapp2/Jinja2.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><b>{{ result.email }}</th>
    <th><b>{{ result.date }}</th>
    <th><b>{{ result.title }}</th>
    <th><b>{{ result.content }}</th>
    <th><a href="/delete/{{ ID GOES HERE }}"</th> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Python:

```
class MyRequestsHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler): # Queries the datastore

def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    userIdentity = users.get_current_user().user_id()
    #email = users.get_current_user().email()
    login_url = users.create_login_url(self.request.path)
    logout_url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.path)

    q = WorkRequest.query(WorkRequest.userId == userIdentity)

    results = q.fetch(10)

    template = template_env.get_template('myrequests.html')
    context = {

        'user': user,
        'login_url': login_url,
        'logout_url': logout_url,
        'results': results,
    }

    self.response.out.write(template.render(context))
```

Comment: Why aren't you sending `userIdentity` to the template?

Comment: @GAEfan I am still experimenting at this stage. Not sure if I will need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a custom ID, or the standard integer ID from ndb?  I think what you want is:

{{ result.key.id() }}

depending on what model you are using.  But you might consider sending a `url safe key` to the template and using that.

Comment: Is `pk` a typo?

Comment: Yeah, django thing.  fixed.